# How to encode or hide querystring in <a> anchor tag in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url, encoding

```
<asp:DataList id="dlmuv" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="Default2.aspx?id=<%#Eval("scid") %>"><asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" class="image_frame" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("latmvimage") %>'  Width="160px" Height="120px"/></a>
            </td>
           <td><a href="Custompage.aspx?id=<%#Eval("patha") %>&img=<%#Eval("imgid") %>">1280 x 800</a>&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp
           </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='<%# Eval("Default2.aspx?id={0}","scid")'><asp:Image .../></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript..

```
<input type = "hidden" id = "hid" value = "101" />
<a id = "lnk" href = "Mypage.aspx">Click</a>
```

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$("#lnk").live("click", function () {
window.location =  $(this).href +'?Id=' + $("#hid").val();
});
</script>
```